# rendering a listViewItem in GridView outside the ListView component

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, listviewitem

The way I know to use ListView in a GridView is this:

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers">
                    <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" />
                            </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

(example from http://www.wpf-tutorial.com)

Now I want to render individual `ListViewItem`s with a defined scheme (columbs) inside a content of something else. (e.g. I want to render a *row* of this table someplace else)

for example: inside a TreeViewItem.

I want this to be able to ultimately create a `TreeView` in which each item contains a row (`ListViewItem`) of the ListView.

Example:

[image]

Is this possible? If so - how to achieve it. 
If the question is not clear, please say so in the comments.

Comment: Have a look at GroupStyle: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Dave M I do not wish to divide the list into groups, I wish to create an hierarchical list...

Comment: How many levels of hierarchy do you need? Your question implies you need 1 level of hierarchy, if so, then there’s no reason Grouping won’t work, and it’s far simpler than alternatives. If you need multiple levels of hierarchy, it becomes real challenging with only built in controls. You can’t just put ListViewItems in a TreeView. You can either find some 3rd party control that does something like you need, or you can fake it with a ListView using templates that give the appearance of hierarchy (I’ve done something like this with DataGrid)

Comment: @DaveM thanks for the answer. I do, in fact, need unlimited levels of hierarchy. I thought about writing a control based on ListView but there is no way to implement the "items" for each item. because ListViewItem is not an ItemControl and I can't inherit from both ItemsControl and ListViewItem. If you know any third party control that does that I would love to know. What do you mean fake it? I would I create the apearance of hierarchy? note that I also want to "expand"/"unexpand" functions to work.

Comment: If you have any clues whether to HOW to implement that kind of control I would love to hear. I would look at the source code of ListView for hints but as far as I know it's not open and I couldn't get enough hints from looking at the xaml code for the default style.